# @SecondaryTable annotation in hibernate issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working in a project with spring framework 4.2.5.RELEASE and Hibernate 5, I'm trying to map an entity with two tables, I have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "programa")   
@SecondaryTable(name="jornada", pkJoinColumns={
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jor_codigo",   referencedColumnName="jor_codigo") })
public class Programa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pro_codigo")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "pro_calendario")
    private Character calendario;

    @Column(name = "pro_registro_snies")
    private String codigoSnies;

    @Column(name = "jor_nombre", table = "jornada")
    private String jornada;

    @Column(name = "pro_propio")
    private boolean propio;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sed_codigo")
    private Sede sede;

    @Column(name = "pro_titulo_otorgado")
    private String tituloOtorgado;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uaa_codigo")
    private Uaa uaa;
    //Setters and getters
}
```

I'm testing with junit and I get this error:

```
Unable to find column with logical name: jor_codigo in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(programa) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

Hope you can help me with this, thanks.

**EDIT**

The columns of the tables are:
 programa columns:

1. pro_codigo ->primary key
2. pro_nombre
3. jor_codigo ->foreign key

jornada columns:

1. jor_codigo ->primary key
2. jor_nombre

Comment: your `referencedColumnName` should be `pro_codigo`

Comment: I forgot to add the tables structure, I'll edit the question and you say if it's still the  ` referencedColumnName`.
Thanks for you quick response.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I checked the result from the test and from sqlserver manager, and looking the sql generated from hibernate I got `left outer join jornada j on p.pro_codigo=j.jor_codigo` it should be `left outer join jornada j on p.jor_codigo=j.jor_codigo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jor_codigo",   referencedColumnName="jor_codigo")
```

your `referencedColumnName` should be `pro_codigo`. so that `jor_codigo` column in 
`jornada` can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jor_codigo",   referencedColumnName="jor_codigo") })`

Here you indicate how you map your secondary entity to your primary entity. Here you want to do it by both entities' id columns.

(`name="main_entity_id_column_name", referencedColumnName="secondary_entity_id_column_name"`)
So in your case `referencedColumnName` should be `pro_codigo`

Comment: I did what you said but when I see the sql query is:
`left outer join jornada this_1_ on this_.pro_codigo=this_1_.jor_codigo` 

Which is not the query I need.

`@SecondaryTable(name="jornada", pkJoinColumns={
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="jor_codigo", referencedColumnName="pro_codigo") })`

Comment: Are you sure this is the structure you need? You have table A and a secondary table B. So you represent A+B as one entity. But also B has a reference to A (foreign key). Either get rid of @SecondaryTable and make OneToOne relation, then you will have the query you want `left outer join jornada j on p.jor_codigo=j.jor_codigo`, or get rid of foreign key, then the query you see on the server is correct. If you really need both (dunno why), then you might need to provide more details, how you create objects and HQL.

Comment: The table 'programa' has a foreign key with the table 'jornada' in the database, I have an entity 'Programa' with an attribute `private String jornada`, which represents the name of the jornada that is in the table 'jornada' as 'jor_nombre', what I want is the left join with jornada to bind the attribute `private String jornada` with the field `jor_nombre`.